# Is there good method to clockwise rotate M*N 2D matrix in place, assuming matrix space of max(M,N)*max(M,N)

Tags: algorithm, matrix

Appreciate any advice. Searched internet but no luck
Assuming the original matrix has big enough size for rotation in place

{{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}} to {{5,3,1},{6,4,2}}

or

1 2

3 4

5 6

clockwise rotation to

5 3 1

6 4 2

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean transpose - if so see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_matrix_transposition. If not, can you give an example?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "assuming enough space"? If an arbitrarily large auxiliary space may be used, it would be misleading to term an operation "in place".

Comment: @Codor, sorry for misleading, enough space means the actual size of matrix would be max(M,N)*max(M,N), so there would not be out of boundary after rotation

Comment: @mcdowella, simple example would be { {1}, {2}, {3} } to { {1,2,3} }

Comment: Surely that simple example is an example of transposition, from a matrix of 3 rows and 1 column to a matrix of 1 row with 3 columns.  This leaves me suspicious that you are still not explaining your requirement properly.  I think a minimal example will require an `m*n` matrix where both `m` and `n` are greater than `1`.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark  Agreed... updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way would be a combination of flipping a matrix left-right or up-down (which can be done trivially by [in-place reversing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm#Examples) of individual columns or rows) and doing an in-place matrix transposition, see mcdowella's [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_matrix_transposition). See for example the [source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.9.1/numpy/lib/twodim_base.py#L137) of Numpy's [rot90](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rot90.html) function which does exactly these two steps (the swapaxis is basically a transpose).

You could do everything in one step, but this might require iterating over the matrix in some sort of spiral pattern. This would cost quite some effort to implement right, and, given the availability of efficient algorithms (e.g. optimized for cache access) for swapping and transposing, this might even be slower.